# Trouble removing NSStrings in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

In an NSArray, I have a 10 values. The values look something like this:

```
Hello
Hello2
My
My2
Name
Name2
Is
Is2
XcodeDev
XcodeDev2
```

And I want to delete every second NSString from the NSArray, so I am left with an array like the following. The values are random, and do not have 2 appended to every second one! How can I do this?

```
Hello
My
Name
Is
XcodeDev
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are going to need an instance of `NSMutableArray`, because `NSArray`s are immutable and therefore, you cannot change its contents.

```
NSMutableArray *ary = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anImmutableArray];
```

Then, you can create an index set that holds all the odd indexes:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i < [ary count]; i=i+2) {
    [indexSet addIndex:i];
}
```

Finally, just call `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` method on the array.

```
[ary removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```